# Jsonschema2pojo error with creating a list of objects with class name as "S"

Tags: json, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I am trying to generate POJOs from a json schema.

Problem :  If I have the class name as "s", it throws an error.

Error from plugin execution:  Execution goal org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:0.4.0:generate failed: String index out of range: 0 -> [Help 1]

I have tried using the maven plugin as well as http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

```
<groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.0</version>
```

Both give errors while generating the pojos.

Other observations : It works for other letters.
If it is not an array type, then plain object works too, but not as an array

Small excerpt of the schema is as below :

```
 { 
  "type": "object",
  "id": "http://jsonschema.net/abc",
  "required": true,
  "description": "Some description",
  "properties": {
  "s": {
          "type": "array",
          "id": "http://jsonschema.net/abc/s",
          "required": true,
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "id": "http://jsonschema.net/price/abc/0/",
            "required": true,
            "description": "sales price object of an item",
            "properties": {
               "ip": {
                "type": "number",
                "id": "http://jsonschema.net/price/p/s/0/value",
                "required": true,
                "description": "some desc"
              }
             }
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Has someone faced a similar issue/known bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Was an issue with the code.  [Issue](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/213) raised and closed - verified in plugin version 0.4.5.